# Standard and portable pseudo random number generator based on seed in C++

Tags: c++, random

If i want to start building a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) in C++ what are the best bricks for the job?

are there any standardize and portable libraries with a predictable behaviour ( with a seed ) and pseudo randomic?

Comment: GSL - GNU Scientific Library http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: The existing pseudo random number generators in the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) or [boost::random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) should be sufficient.

Comment: @lukas GSL is out because of the license, rand() is trivial, is also probably just the opposite of what i'm looking for, there isn't the concept of seed and predictable behaviour in rand()

Comment: @Mysticial see my previous comment

Comment: `rand()` **is** seedable and consistent (if that's what you mean by predictable). Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @JesseGood Boost is an extremely good library but on some platform is still not so trivial to build and some part of it not "an header only" library so you have to fight a lot with platforms that get C++ support but do not make boost available. I would take a look to the reference for C++.

Comment: @hthy46vbs You can use `srand()` to seed the sequence generated by `rand()`.

Comment: @hthy46vbs I doubt you'll find a more portable uniform random implementation than boost's.

Comment: @Mysticial rand() returns a values that is in the user input range, doesn't create the mix between a faked entropy and a predictible behaviour, if you input 0 and 100 you get something between 0-100 and this is not a precise and predictible behaviour to me.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. Could you reword it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "portable" I assume you want the same sequence of random numbers given the same seed, no matter which platform they're compiled for. Pseudo-random number generators should provide the same sequence as long as they're based on the same algorithm. I think [boost::random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) is your best bet, it's a good random number generator (better than `rand` in many cases) with predictable behavior across platforms.

Comment: Even if it wasn't, and you needed it to be, your best bet would still be to take the boost code as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 offers a host of portable random-number generators. This was driven by the folks at Fermilab, who do heavy-duty simulations of subatomic particle interactions, often involving distributing work through a network to many computers.

Comment: While the standard random number generators are portable, the distributions in the standard are not constrained to output the same sequences on different platforms for the same seeds. I was sad to learn this, and now use boost's instead.